# Convert text file to ASCII, nothing more, in Sublime Text

Tags: text-editors, sublime-text-2, character-encoding, ascii, file-conversion

We have a project where we need to convert weird characters generated from all kinds of file formats into ASCII due to compatibility issues.  Is it possible in Sublime Text 2 to convert the encoding of a document to ASCII?  We can't convert it to any extended/non-ASCII character set if it includes more characters that are not supported.

Comment: 7-bit ASCII has no support for "weird characters". So you want to just remove them from the file? If so, open with any 8 bit encoding and search for regular expression `[\x80-\xff]`, replacing it with nothing.

Comment: ANSI is the organization that made ASCII so your question makes no sense.

Comment: @barlop - Windows incorrectly refers to non-Unicode character sets as "ANSI" code pages, so that may be the source of the confusion.

Comment: The OP specifically says he wants to "convert weird characters ... into ASCII".   What does this in fact mean?  Ignore them?  Replace with ASCII SUB (0x1A)?  Insert some "equivalent" sequence?

Comment: @dave well I think it often means he wants all chars to be within 0-127 For example,  if you paste some stuff from online into notepad and try to save, the default is what notepad calls "ANSI" and anything > 127 , when saving with ansi(which is default), will cause a prompt to say "the file contains characters in a format that will be lost".   If saved the file may end up with lots of question mark characters in there in place of the >127 character.

Comment: @dave Often these >127 chars are eg curly left quote and curly right quote  `“......”` (which can be easily replaced with a regular quote `"`)  , a non-breaking space that can b replaced with a space.A variety of weird characters can find their way in and easily be replaced with a regular < 128, and notepad will easily save the file without changing encoding.(though personally I find it's usually quicker2change the encoding!) But since having chars >127 is often unnecessary(and might make the file larger and don't sit well with notepad's default),I can c how somebody might want to change them

Comment: @DanielBeck " regular expression [\x80-\xff], replacing it with nothing" <-- well, may want to do specific ones like replacing curly quotes.. That regex is good for finding the thing one could then see what char it is(I sometimes copy/paste the char into word put the cursor after it and do alt-x),  and then decide what to do with it.. 
 This question here https://superuser.com/questions/985570/how-do-i-find-this-characterby-unicode-search-in-notepad-%EF%BB%81-ufec1-and-only/986109    mentions doing e.g. in notepad++ \x{FEC1}  So eg for when you have a utf16 code for a character.

Comment: He might want something that does search and replace across multiple files. Sublime probably could but it's not built specifically for that, it may need some clever python within sublime scripting skills

Comment: @barlop - ok, fair enough; I merely wanted the OP to clarify intent.  So we either need a conversion that implements a standardized set of "close enough" equivalents, or else a conversion that allows the user to specify what they are.

Comment: Okay so, this is SIX YEARS OLD.  I can't even remember what I ate for breakfast sometimes, nor what I was doing for a project then.  Even though I'm not sure specifically what I was even asking either, I've changed it so hopefully @barlop can sleep at night.  If it's not to your liking, hopefully someone will just delete the question for all I care. - The OP

Comment: @jfraczek you asked your question very poorly then. You are meant to ask your question in such a way that anybody reading it (be it your future self or anybody else), knows what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

Sublime text 2 will allow you to save with a variety of encodings, but won't do so if you have characters that don't fit in the encoding you are saving to. I had a problem recently were I was getting encoding errors at various positions in Mako templates and since the characters were not displayable in sublime text I couldn't even see them to remove them. So I opened the file in the hex editor HxD changed the offset base to decimal and went straight to the positions specified in the errors and removed the offending characters; Problem solved.

Also it didn't help me in this case but you might find this useful.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943594/is-it-possible-to-show-the-exact-position-in-sublime-text-2
The link above includes source that if saved to Preferences > Browse Packages > User will add absolute position of the cursor to the status line at the bottom of the Sublime Text window, though this didn't help me since the offending characters weren't displayable.

Comment: You wrote "changed the offset base to decimal"  What. Why don't you state what hex editor that was.  It's not clear what changing the offset base to decimal means until reading where you later write "the positions specified in the errors"  But then it's not that clear what you mean a'cos you haven't shown the errors you mean. I get the jist of what you're saying but you are writing very unclearly, stating things later that should be said earlier, and not giving examples.